# Why can't I display a new image using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a page that allows viewers to view a new image every time the user clicks on it. The images are named 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, and 4.jpg.

However, the image URL never changes upon clicking. I also tried analyzing the image in Chrome Developer tools, and the console issues no errors. Why is that?

Here is my javascript.

```
var imageCount = 5;
var currentIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageCount);

  function loadNewPhoto() {
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + (Math.random() * 3) + 1) % imageCount;
    alert(currentIndex);
    document.getElementById('generatedImage').src = 'images/' + currentIndex + '.jpg';
  }

  // Shuffle order of photos.
  document.onready = function() {
    loadNewPhoto();
    document.getElementById('getMeNewPhotoLink').onclick(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      loadNewPhoto();
    });
  }
```

and HTML

```
<a href="#" id="getMeNewPhotoLink">
    <img id="generatedImage" src="images/0.jpg" alt="" />
</a>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qLQZf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working here is your [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uzizur/5/edit#preview)

New HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:shuffle()" id="getMeNewPhotoLink" >
    <img id="generatedImage" src="images/0.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

`href` is now a javascript function instead of `"#"`, a more elegant solution

New Javascript:

```
var imageCount = 5;
var currentIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageCount);
alert(currentindex);
  function loadNewPhoto() {
    currentIndex = Math.floor((currentIndex + (Math.random() * 3) + 1) % imageCount);//Added Math.floor, else was generating decimal value
    alert(currentIndex);
    document.getElementById('generatedImage').src = 'images/' + currentIndex + '.jpg';
  }

  // Shuffle order of photos, no need of preventdefault, onclick and ready event handling via code.

  function shuffle() {
     loadNewPhoto();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! That's great. The href attribute sure is nice. Do you how I call loadNewPhoto when the page loads as well?

Comment: Add this to your body onload="shuffle()"

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, you were assigning the `onclick` handler incorrectly. It should be:

```
document.getElementById('getMeNewPhotoLink').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  loadNewPhoto();
};
```